# Magento 1.9 - Sales Order Invoice Pdf font Chinese not working

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice-pdf

I have a problem with Chinese fonts. I edited the file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php
Or even override it but the font remains unchanged.

Override:
app/code/local/Module/Pdf/etc/config.php

```
<sales>
    <rewrite>
        <order_pdf_invoice>Module_Pdf_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice</order_pdf_invoice>
        <order_pdf_abstract>Module_Pdf_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract</order_pdf_abstract>
    </rewrite>
</sales>
```

app/code/local/Module/Pdf/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php

```
class Module_Pdf_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice {
/**
 * Set font as regular
 *
 * @param  Zend_Pdf_Page $object
 * @param  int $size
 * @return Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font
 */
protected function _setFontRegular($object, $size = 7)
{
    $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(Mage::getBaseDir() . '/lib/LinLibertineFont/NotoSansSC-Regular.ttf');
    $object->setFont($font, $size);
    return $font;
}

/**
 * Set font as bold
 *
 * @param  Zend_Pdf_Page $object
 * @param  int $size
 * @return Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font
 */
protected function _setFontBold($object, $size = 7)
{
    $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(Mage::getBaseDir() . '/lib/LinLibertineFont/NotoSansSC-Regular.ttf');
    $object->setFont($font, $size);
    return $font;
}

/**
 * Set font as italic
 *
 * @param  Zend_Pdf_Page $object
 * @param  int $size
 * @return Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font
 */
protected function _setFontItalic($object, $size = 7)
{
    $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(Mage::getBaseDir() . '/lib/LinLibertineFont/NotoSansSC-Regular.ttf');
    $object->setFont($font, $size);
    return $font;
}
```

Can anyone help me handle this problem?
Thank you very much.

[image: Error font Chinese]

Comment: Please head over to https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts and raise an issue/discussion. Guess youll get more help there.

Comment: Thank @sv3n for helping me.